# How can make a button on a nav that scrolls to a specific point in the page, but shorthand

Tags: javascript

I have written four functions for buttons on my nav bar that scroll to specific points on the page

```
function scrollToTop() {
  var section = document.querySelector(".body");
  section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}

function scrollToAbout() {
  var section = document.querySelector(".about-me");
  section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}

function scrollToProjects() {
  var section = document.querySelector(".projects");
  section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}

function scrollToContact() {
  var section = document.querySelector(".footer");
  section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

Is there any way I can write this shorter?

Thank you

Comment: How about creating a function that takes the selector as a parameter and does the rest?

Answer (score 2):

There would be a shorter way if you used the css class name as a variable e.g.

```
function scrollTo(className) {
  document.querySelector(className).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });  
}
```

You could then call the function like:

```
<button onclick="scrollTo('.projects')">Projects</button>
```